# Is it possible to use a smart ptr or boost intrusive ptr as the "void* tag" value in a gRPC async server written in C++

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost, grpc

I'm writing an async gRPC server in C++ (on windows). I'd like to use the boost intrusive pointer type for the 'tag' value - the pointer to the RPC handler objects which are returned during the completion queue 'Next()' method.

The gRPC async service requires passing a void* to the handler object so it can call the handler when the associated event occurs. The problem is that I'm unable to find a way to convert my boost intrusive pointer to a void* in a way that preserves and uses the reference count.

Is it possible? Or would it only work if the method I pass the pointer to expects a boost pointer?

Comment: Of course it can. Though the param cannot own the resource, but you can put the ownership in some suitable location

Comment: thanks @sehe - but it seems like that's losing the feature of a smart pointer. If I'm tracking the resource then why use a smart pointer. Or am I missing something?

Comment: You are not losing that feature. It's just that the third-party library does NOT track ownership.

Comment: My understanding of how to compensate for that is to manually call the equivalent of AddRef() when giving it to the third-party library; then calling AddRef() when I get it from the library and then Release() when done using it. Is that the way it has to be done...or is there another way?

Comment: no, you cannot pass the ownership to the third party library (they don't support it). However, I'll try to cook up an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say we have a third party library that takes static callback functions, which can use a `void*` userdata to pass user-defined state around:

```
namespace SomeAPI {
    typedef void(*Callback)(int, void* userdata);

    struct Registration;

    Registration const* register_callback(Callback cb, void* userdata);
    size_t deregister_callback(Callback cb, void* userdata);
    void some_operation_invoking_callbacks();
}
```

A minimalist implementation of this fake API is e.g.:

```
struct Registration {
    Callback cb;
    void* userdata;
};
std::list<Registration> s_callbacks;

Registration const* register_callback(Callback cb, void* userdata) {
    s_callbacks.push_back({cb, userdata});
    return &s_callbacks.back();
}

size_t deregister_callback(Callback cb, void* userdata) {
    auto oldsize = s_callbacks.size(); // c++20 makes this unnecessary
    s_callbacks.remove_if([&](Registration const& r) {
        return std::tie(r.cb, r.userdata) == std::tie(cb, userdata);
    });
    return oldsize - s_callbacks.size();
}

void some_operation_invoking_callbacks() {
    static int s_counter = 0;
    for (auto& reg : s_callbacks) {
        reg.cb(++s_counter, reg.userdata);
    }
}
```

### Let's Have A Client

The Client owns state which is managed by some shared pointer:

```
struct MyClient {
    struct State {
        std::string greeting;

        void foo(int i) {
            std::cout
                << "State::foo with i:" << i
                << " and greeting:" << std::quoted(greeting)
                << "\n";
        }
    };
    using SharedState = std::shared_ptr<State>;
    SharedState state_;
```

Now, we want the `State::foo` member to be registered as a callback, and the `state_` should be passed as the user-data:

```
    MyClient(std::string g) : state_(std::make_shared<State>(State{g})) {
        SomeAPI::register_callback(static_handler, &state_);
    }

    ~MyClient() noexcept {
        SomeAPI::deregister_callback(static_handler, &state_);
    }

    static void static_handler(int i, void* userdata) {
        auto& state = *static_cast<SharedState*>(userdata);
        state->foo(i);
    }
};
```

Now to exercise the Client a bit:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2653c28bae1a5979)**

```
int main() {
    MyClient client1("Foo");

    std::cout << " ------- operation start\n";
    SomeAPI::some_operation_invoking_callbacks();

    {
        MyClient client2("Bar");
        std::cout << " ------- operation start\n";
        SomeAPI::some_operation_invoking_callbacks();
    }

    std::cout << " ------- operation start\n";
    SomeAPI::some_operation_invoking_callbacks();
}
```

Prints:

```
 ------- operation start
State::foo with i:1 and greeting:"Foo"
 ------- operation start
State::foo with i:2 and greeting:"Foo"
State::foo with i:3 and greeting:"Bar"
 ------- operation start
State::foo with i:4 and greeting:"Foo"
```

### Tight-Rope Act

If you **actually** want to pass ownership to the API, in the sense that it keeps the state around even if the `Client` instance is gone, you will, by definition, leak that state.

The only solution to this would be if the API had some kind of callback to signal that it should cleanup up. I've never seen such an API design, but here is what it would look like for this:

```
enum { TEARDOWN_MAGIC_VALUE = -1 };
void InitAPI() {}
void ShutdownAPI() {
    for (auto it = s_callbacks.begin(); it != s_callbacks.end();) {
        it->cb(TEARDOWN_MAGIC_VALUE, it->userdata);
        it = s_callbacks.erase(it);
    }
}
```

Now we can pass a dynamically allocated copy of the `shared_ptr` to the call-back as user-data (instead of a raw pointer to the *owned* copy of the shared pointer):

```
SomeAPI::register_callback(static_handler, new SharedState(state_));
```

Note that because `SomeAPI` now has a **copy** of the shared-pointer, the refcount has increaed. In fact, we don't have to deregister the callback anymore because the State will stay valid, until `SomeAPI` actually shuts down:

```
static void static_handler(int i, void* userdata) {
    auto* sharedstate = static_cast<SharedState*>(userdata);
    if (i == SomeAPI::TEARDOWN_MAGIC_VALUE) {
        delete sharedstate; // decreases refcount
        return;
    } else {
        (*sharedstate)->foo(i);
    }
}
```

The main program is basically un-altered, but for `InitAPI()` and `ShutdownAPI()` calls:

```
int main() {
    SomeAPI::InitAPI();

    MyClient client1("Foo");

    std::cout << " ------- operation start\n";
    SomeAPI::some_operation_invoking_callbacks();

    {
        MyClient client2("Bar");
        std::cout << " ------- operation start\n";
        SomeAPI::some_operation_invoking_callbacks();
    }

    std::cout << " ------- operation start\n";
    SomeAPI::some_operation_invoking_callbacks();

    SomeAPI::ShutdownAPI();
}
```

Through some clever tracing of destructors, you can verify that lifetime of `State` is now actually governed/shared by `ShutdownAPI`:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d6059d7460b80808)**

```
 ------- operation start
State::foo with i:1 and greeting:"Foo"
 ------- operation start
State::foo with i:2 and greeting:"Foo"
State::foo with i:3 and greeting:"Bar"
~MyClient (Bar)
 ------- operation start
State::foo with i:4 and greeting:"Foo"
State::foo with i:5 and greeting:"Bar"
~State (Bar)
~MyClient (Foo)
~State (Foo)
```

### Full Listing (Classic)

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2653c28bae1a5979)**

```
#include <memory>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

namespace SomeAPI {
    using Callback = void(*)(int, void* userdata);

    struct Registration {
        Callback cb;
        void* userdata;
    };
    std::list<Registration> s_callbacks;

    Registration const* register_callback(Callback cb, void* userdata) {
        s_callbacks.push_back({cb, userdata});
        return &s_callbacks.back();
    }

    size_t deregister_callback(Callback cb, void* userdata) {
        auto oldsize = s_callbacks.size(); // c++20 makes this unnecessary
        s_callbacks.remove_if([&](Registration const& r) {
            return std::tie(r.cb, r.userdata) == std::tie(cb, userdata);
        });
        return oldsize - s_callbacks.size();
    }

    void some_operation_invoking_callbacks() {
        static int s_counter = 0;
        for (auto& reg : s_callbacks) {
            reg.cb(++s_counter, reg.userdata);
        }
    }
}

struct MyClient {
    struct State {
        std::string greeting;

        void foo(int i) {
            std::cout
                << "State::foo with i:" << i
                << " and greeting:" << std::quoted(greeting)
                << "\n";
        }
    };
    using SharedState = std::shared_ptr<State>;
    SharedState state_;

    MyClient(std::string g) : state_(std::make_shared<State>(State{g})) {
        SomeAPI::register_callback(static_handler, &state_);
    }

    ~MyClient() noexcept {
        SomeAPI::deregister_callback(static_handler, &state_);
    }

    static void static_handler(int i, void* userdata) {
        auto& state = *static_cast<SharedState*>(userdata);
        state->foo(i);
    }
};

int main() {
    MyClient client1("Foo");

    std::cout << " ------- operation start\n";
    SomeAPI::some_operation_invoking_callbacks();

    {
        MyClient client2("Bar");
        std::cout << " ------- operation start\n";
        SomeAPI::some_operation_invoking_callbacks();
    }

    std::cout << " ------- operation start\n";
    SomeAPI::some_operation_invoking_callbacks();
}
```

### Full Listing (Contrived)

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d6059d7460b80808)**

```
#include <memory>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

namespace SomeAPI {
    enum { TEARDOWN_MAGIC_VALUE = -1 };
    using Callback = void(*)(int, void* userdata);

    struct Registration {
        Callback cb;
        void* userdata;
    };
    std::list<Registration> s_callbacks;

    Registration const* register_callback(Callback cb, void* userdata) {
        s_callbacks.push_back({cb, userdata});
        return &s_callbacks.back();
    }

    size_t deregister_callback(Callback cb, void* userdata) {
        auto oldsize = s_callbacks.size(); // c++20 makes this unnecessary
        s_callbacks.remove_if([&](Registration const& r) {
            bool const matched = std::tie(r.cb, r.userdata) == std::tie(cb, userdata);
            if (matched) {
                r.cb(TEARDOWN_MAGIC_VALUE, r.userdata);
            }
            return matched;
        });
        return oldsize - s_callbacks.size();
    }

    void some_operation_invoking_callbacks() {
        static int s_counter = 0;
        for (auto& reg : s_callbacks) {
            reg.cb(++s_counter, reg.userdata);
        }
    }

    void InitAPI() {}
    void ShutdownAPI() {
        for (auto it = s_callbacks.begin(); it != s_callbacks.end();) {
            it->cb(TEARDOWN_MAGIC_VALUE, it->userdata);
            it = s_callbacks.erase(it);
        }
    }
}

struct MyClient {
    struct State {
        std::string greeting;
        State(std::string g) : greeting(std::move(g)) {}

        void foo(int i) {
            std::cout
                << "State::foo with i:" << i
                << " and greeting:" << std::quoted(greeting)
                << "\n";
        }

        ~State() noexcept {
            std::cout << "~State (" << greeting << ")\n";
        }
    };
    using SharedState = std::shared_ptr<State>;
    SharedState state_;

    MyClient(std::string g) : state_(std::make_shared<State>(std::move(g))) {
        SomeAPI::register_callback(static_handler, new SharedState(state_));
    }

    ~MyClient() {
        std::cout << "~MyClient (" << state_->greeting << ")\n";
    }

    static void static_handler(int i, void* userdata) {
        auto* sharedstate = static_cast<SharedState*>(userdata);
        if (i == SomeAPI::TEARDOWN_MAGIC_VALUE) {
            delete sharedstate; // decreases refcount
            return;
        } else {
            (*sharedstate)->foo(i);
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    SomeAPI::InitAPI();

    MyClient client1("Foo");

    std::cout << " ------- operation start\n";
    SomeAPI::some_operation_invoking_callbacks();

    {
        MyClient client2("Bar");
        std::cout << " ------- operation start\n";
        SomeAPI::some_operation_invoking_callbacks();
    }

    std::cout << " ------- operation start\n";
    SomeAPI::some_operation_invoking_callbacks();

    SomeAPI::ShutdownAPI();
}
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time to produce this example. I'm going to copy it and step through it to fully understand, and check in again in a few days. Thanks again.

Comment: Cheers! Good luck

Comment: These examples fully illustrate how to work with shared pointers when using an API that doesn't understand what a shared pointer is. For my particular use case, I'm using the allocated pointer (the 'contrived' method above). The object that is referenced by the smart pointer is the only thing that knows its state, so it has to manage its own lifetime by deleting the allocated pointer when its state is 'done'. It will hand out weak pointers to anything that it interacts with so they can test for the object's validity.